# Adding days into date

Tags: c

I have found the solution to change the year but i am unable to add the dates of months having 31 days, can you tell me where i am wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        int dd,mm,yy,numb_days,temp;

        printf("Enter date in format(DD/MM/YYY format):");
        scanf("%d/%d/%d",&dd,&mm,&yy);

    printf("Enter number of days:");
    scanf("%d",&numb_days);

    if ((dd+numb_days) < 30)    {
       dd = dd + numb_days;
    }
    if (mm ==12){
        yy++;
    }
     if ((dd+numb_days)< 31)
{
    temp = (dd+numb_days) -31;
    mm++;
    dd=temp;
}
     else   { 
         temp= (dd+numb_days) - 30; 
         mm++;
         dd=temp;
     }
     printf("%d/%d/%d",dd,mm,yy);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: You question has nothing to do with C, really. I suggest you take the time to work out how you'd calculate a date without a computer, use a piece of paper and a pen.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're not here to do your homework for you; you've got to at least try to write the program first.

Comment: any hint for months having 31 days

Comment: You may want to convert your values to [`struct tm`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/time.h.html), then add the days which will normalize automatically.

Comment: @pmg sir i want to use if else and printf statements only without any built in functions.

Comment: Another possible option is converting to [Julian day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) and back. Good luck using only `if`, `else`, and `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

It is against the rules but looks like u are new so i am going to answer 
you have taken the input 
so you could do the rest like this

```
int numb_days;
int temp;
scanf("%d" ,&numb_days);


if ((dd+numb_days) < 30)
    dd = dd + numb_days;
else 
     temp= (dd+numb_days) - 30 ; 
     mm++;
     dd=temp;
```

now the date is updated

Comment: (1) Doing someone's homework for them isn't constructive. (2) Different months have a different number of days. And adding to December will also bump the year.

Comment: first of all i didn't give the exact solution, just an idea 
secondly as i mentioned he seemed new so  i answered

Comment: Being new doesn't excuse one from staying on-topic. You are still doing the OP a major disservice here (and yourself, since they can rightfully pester you now until you work up an entire solution for them) by inhibiting their learning.

Comment: you can set up  2 if conditions 
(1) for 30 days 
(2) for 31 days 
and then enter those conditions using the month number for example if the month number is 1 (i.e january) 
it could go in the **if conditon** of 31 days
if month number is 11 (i.e november) you could go in the other if condition

Comment: and then you will have another problem for february but you can solve it on your own

Comment: so if i write:       if(dd ==31);
                temp = (dd+numb_days) -31;
                 mm++;
                       dd=temp;

Comment: more like if (mm == 1 || mm == 3 || mm==5 || mm == 7 || mm == 8 || mm == 10 || mm == 12) {if ((dd+numb_days)>31) { temp = (dd+numb_days) -31; mm++; dd=temp;} }